# Gulp перенос файлов с изменением структуры каталогов

Tags: javascript, gulp

Как в *Gulp* реализовать перенос файла, с изменением структуры?

К примеру, чтобы из:

```
/modules/
--/m1/
----/public/
------/index.js
```

получить:

```
/build/
--/m1/
----/index.js
```

Иными словами, нужно избавиться от папки `public`.

Comment: А могут существовать другие каталоги на одном и том же уровне с `m1`? Их тоже нужно переносить?

Comment: Да, могут быть и другие каталоги, просто перенести не сложно, но как избавиться от папки, в середине пути, пока не понял.

Comment: см. мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 3):

В экосистеме Gulp существует огромное количество плагинов. Для решения своей задачи вы вполне можете использовать один из них, а именно [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename). Этот плагин позволяет использовать произвольную функцию обратного вызова для изменения имен перемещаемых файлов. А вот пример того, как этот плагин можно использовать:

**gulpfile.js**:

```
var dirSep = require('path').sep,
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('modules/*/public/**/*')
        .pipe(rename(function(path) {
            // Переменная dirSep содержит разделитель директорий для
            // текущей ОС. Этот хак позволяет проводить сборку как в
            // Linux так и в Windows системах.
            var dirs = path.dirname.split(dirSep);

            dirs.splice(1, 1);
            path.dirname = dirs.join(dirSep)
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

**package.json**:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2"
    }
}
```