# Перенос файлов в gulp с изменением структуры каталогов

Tags: node.js, gulp

Файловая структура

```
project
  gulpfile.js
  build
    css
    img
      logo.png
      background.jpg
    index.html
  src
    blocks
      header
        header.pug
        header.styl
        logo.png
        background.jpg
      section
      footer
    main.styl
    index.pug
```

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

 var gulp = require('gulp');

 gulp.task('move:images', function(){
   return gulp.src('src/**/*.{png,jpg}')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img'));
 });
```

Нужно было, чтоб gulp перенес все картинки из директории `src` в директорию `build/img`. По умолчанию gulp переносит картинки копируя путь к картинке рекурсивно, например, если копировать `src/blocks/header/logo.png` получится `build/img/blocks/header/logo.png`. Мне надо, чтоб получилось `build/img/logo.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрев [Gulp 3: Потоки Vinyl-FS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBdKplKl_3Q), выяснил, что `blocks/header/logo.png` это относительный путь к файлу и решил, что мне нужно изменить часть относительного пути убрав директории, чтоб получить `build/img/logo.png`.

Стал искать, как это сделать и нашел в API Node.js [path.relative(from, to)](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to), но он меняет относительный путь целиком, а не его часть. Далее нашел [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename).

[Gulp перенос файлов с изменением структуры каталогов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463406/gulp-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2) помог реализовать желаемое. Получившийся таск.

```
gulp.task('move:images', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.{png,jpg}')
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
      var dirs = path.dirname.split(dirSep);
      dirs.splice(0, 2);
      path.dirname = dirs.join(dirSep)
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img'));
});
```

Появились другие вопросы на который сам не могу ответить.

В строке `dirs.splice(0, 2);` явно указывается сколько удалить, в моем случае точно известно, что `/blocks/header/`, но может же быть и бОльшая вложенность, не создавать же отдельный таск под нее, можно как то автоматизировать определение директорий?

Возможна ли отмена рекурсивного копирования директорий при сохранении рекурсивного прохода по директориям в поисках файлов?

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

gulp.task('move:images', function(){
   return gulp.src('src/**/*.{png,jpg}')
   .pipe(flatten({ includeParents: 0 }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img'));
 });
```