# gulp dest без сохранения структуры

Tags: gulp

Как вставить файлы без сохранения структуры?

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
'use strict';
return gulp.src(['app/pages/*.njk','app/blocks/**/*.njk'])
.pipe(rename({extname: ".html"})) // допустим мы поменяли формат
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist')) // теперь нужно чтобы все файлы бы ли в одной папке dist
});
```

Comment: `gulp.dest('./dist/')`? Ваш код по идее все и сохраняет в одну папку, с путями ошиблись возможно

Comment: Попробуйте адаптировать код из [этого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463406/gulp-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 2):

Измените код таска так:

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
'use strict';
return gulp.src(['app/pages/*.njk','app/blocks/**/*.njk'])
.pipe(rename({
extname: ".html",// допустим мы поменяли формат
dirname: "" // убираем лишние каталоги из пути(то есть имени файла) 
})) 
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist')) // теперь нужно чтобы все файлы бы ли в одной папке dist
});
```

Будет складывать в dist без лишних каталогов.